# IHttpContextAccessor session invalid operation exception in CustomClaimsTransformer

Tags: asp.net-core, session, dependency-injection, httpcontext

I followed the official docs to access the HttpContext from custom components in a CustomClaimsTransformer.

I previously had a .NET Core web application, where I used the session to enable admins to jump into the application with the view (identity) of a different user (for support purposes). I store the information, for which user the view should be prepared in the Session. Now I wanted to make it more elegant and use the .net core authorization using claims and role based authorization. As there is a Windows authentication behind, I’ve to use the CustomClaimsTransformer. Now my problem is, I want to access the current session from within the CustomClaimsTransformer. I can inject the IHttpContextAccessor, but IHttpContextAccessor.Session always raises an invalid operation exception.

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");
        });
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
            options.AddPolicy("Test1", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Rechte", " Test1"));
            options.AddPolicy("Test2", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Rechte", " Test2"));

        });

        services.AddMvc(config =>
             {
                 var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                 config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
             }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        //services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, CustomClaimsTransformer>();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
    }
```

CustomClaimsTransformer:

```
CustomClaimsTransformer:
public class CustomClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public CustomClaimsTransformer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }


    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var z = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext; //works
        var zz = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session; // System.InvalidOperationException: "Session has not been configured for this application or request."
```

I edited my ConfigureServices above, when pasting the code I removed some lines for readability, including the AddDistributedMemoryCache line, sorry. Session is working in the app except where shown.

Configure:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you included `app.UseSession();` in `Configure` method?

Answer (score 2):

Reference [Session and app state in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

> To enable the session middleware, `Startup` must contain:
>
> - Any of the `IDistributedCache` memory caches. The `IDistributedCache` implementation is used as a backing store for
>     session.
> - A call to `AddSession` in `ConfigureServices`.
> - A call to `UseSession` in `Configure`.

Also

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

    //... removed for brevity

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession(); // This must come before "UseMvc()"
    app.UseHttpContextItemsMiddleware();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

> The order of middleware is important. In the preceding example, an
>   `InvalidOperationException` exception occurs when `UseSession` is
>   invoked after `UseMvc`.
>   ...
>   `HttpContext.Session` can't be accessed before `UseSession` has been called.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I edited my question.

Comment: @Fritz where is `IClaimsTransformation` being used? in a middle-ware. controller or some other service?

Comment: according to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation.transformasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_IClaimsTransformation_TransformAsync_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_) TransformAsync will be run on each AuthenticateAsync call, so its safer to return a new ClaimsPrincipal if your transformation is not idempotent.

Comment: @Fritz what is the actual exception being thrown. Just realized it was not included in the OP

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: "Session has not been configured for this application or request." (in the last posted line in CustomClaimsTransformer:
var zz = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session; )